# Single website - many businesses, linking each individual account to the Facebook account

Tags: php, facebook

I operate www.yespanya.com

On the site, each business his its own page, full of useful information.  My clients add discount vouchers, special offers and entertainment on a regular basis.

I would like to add the ability to link each client account with their own Facebook account, so that we can update their individual Facebook account programmatically - after entering their user credentials only once.

This way, as they update the offer on our site, this will simultaneously update their Facebook page.

I am certain this is possible, but do not know what to look for, or any relevant API we should use?

Grateful for any assistance.